# What are all the math packages about?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, unicode-math, mathtools

I have counted 48 packages in `MikTeX Package Manager` which have `math` as a part of their names. What are all those packages about? Who could provide a short or not-so-short review of these packages? `Voss-mathmode`, one of those packages provides such a review, but it was written almost 10 years ago. I guess that those packages can be divided by several groups whithin wich some packages do similar things, e.g. provides math fonts.

List of packages follows.
[image]
[image]

Comment: `texdoc <name of package>`? And doesn't the *Title* column in your images say what most of those are about?

Comment: Sounds very much like a "do it for me" question. Or is there any reason why you can't provide such a list with the help of the docus, Herberts text and the CTAN descriptions?

Answer (score 7):

While searching the TeXLive utility for the string "math", either in the name of the package or in the short description, one gets well more than 110 "hits". The list shown below is certainly not exhaustive; for instance, the `newtx` and `newpx` packages, which provide Times and Palatino text and math fonts, respectively, aren't included in this list.

The packages cover a broad range of services: Some provide fonts (e.g., `eulervm`, `fouriernc`, `kpfonts`, `pxfonts`, `stix`, `txfonts`, and `xits`), others provide macros and environments relevant in various fields of mathematics and physics (`amsmath` and `mathtools`, amongst many), and still others provide specialized document classes or other services. Some packages work with all TeX engines, while others (e.g., `unicode-math`) require either XeTeX or LuaTeX. The majority of packages appears to be maintained, but one suspects that quite a few are not.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Similar selection by `math` as a keyword in MikTeX Package Manager gives 240 packages.

Comment: does not include packages relative to math computations such as  `apnum`, `pgfmath`, `xfp`, `xint`, ...

Comment: @jfbu - Thanks. I did take pains to note, in the first paragraph, that the "list shown below is certainly not exhaustive".

Comment: I was not meaning to imply that the list needed some extras, but (I was too terse) that in the TeX world, "math" is mainly associated with typesetting (TeX math mode being a world in its own), hence does not have the colloquial meaning of the word "math". From this point of view, the packages I cited do not belong to the list indeed. (That TeX is associated with typesetting will surely not surprise people here ...)